# Hibernate is not fetching latest inserted record from database

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to fetch data from database. the method `insert()` is calling `fetch()`.

In `insert()` I am getting `billNo` after insertion to data base  `(Long) data.get("billNo")` is getting bill no .

In `System.out.println("no is "+(Long) data.get("billNo"));`  I am printing value which is displaying proper value.

```
   public void insert(){
     Map data = dao.insertBill(bd);
            String ss = (String) data.get("status");
            if (ss.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                List<Object[]> aa = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
                System.out.println("no is " + (Long) data.get("billNo"));//op 56
                aa = dao.fetch((Long) data.get("billNo"), lc.getClient().getId());
                System.out.println(" aa length is " + aa.size());//0
                Object[] bdAndSum = aa.get(0);//line 122 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                  .....
                }
    }
```

Fetch Method

```
public List<Object[]> fetch(Long id, long cid) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List<Object[]> obj = null;
    System.out.println("id " + id + " cid " + cid);

    try {
        String hql = "select distinct bd,sum(bpds.amount) from BillDetails as bd "
                + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                + "left join fetch bd.billProductSet as bpd "
                + "left join fetch bpd.product as pd "
                + "left join fetch bd.billPaidDetails as bpds "
                + "where bd.billNo=:id "
                + "and bd.client.id=:cid "
                + "group by bpd.id";

        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.setParameter("cid", cid);
        System.out.println("id " + id + " cid " + cid);//id 56 cid 1
        obj = query.list();
        System.out.println("id " + id + " cid " + cid);//id 56 cid 1
        System.out.println("Printing size of obj ");
        System.out.println(" " + obj.size());//0

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx != null) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

My problem is `dao.fetch((Long) data.get("billNo"), lc.getClient().getId());` is not fetching data from database and
and giving exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    iland.bill.BillNewAction.insert(BillNewAction.java:122)
```

but if I am calling `dao.fetch(56, lc.getClient().getId());`

it is fetching data from database.

How to resolve this.

Edit:
server console data

```
no is 82
id 82 cid 1
id 82 cid 1
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        distinct bd,
        sum(bpds.amount) 
    from
        BillDetails as bd 
    left join
        fetch bd.customerDetails as cd 
    left join
        fetch bd.billProductSet as bpd 
    left join
        fetch bpd.product as pd 
    left join
        fetch bd.billPaidDetails as bpds 
    where
        bd.billNo=:id 
        and bd.client.id=:cid 
    group by
        bpd.id */ select
            distinct billdetail0_.bill_no as col_0_0_,
            sum(billpaidde4_.amount) as col_1_0_,
            customerde1_.id as id10_1_,
            billproduc2_.product_id as product1_15_2_,
            billproduc2_.bill_no as bill2_15_2_,
            product3_.id as id4_3_,
            billpaidde4_.id as id8_4_,
            billdetail0_.bill_no as bill1_0_0_,
            customerde1_.id as id10_1_,
            billproduc2_.product_id as product1_15_2_,
            billproduc2_.bill_no as bill2_15_2_,
            product3_.id as id4_3_,
            billpaidde4_.id as id8_4_,
            billdetail0_.customer_id as customer2_0_0_,
            billdetail0_.cid as cid0_0_,
            billdetail0_.sub_total as sub4_0_0_,
            billdetail0_.vat as vat0_0_,
            billdetail0_.total as total0_0_,
            billdetail0_.invoice_no as invoice7_0_0_,
            billdetail0_.invoice_dt as invoice8_0_0_,
            billdetail0_.status as status0_0_,
            billdetail0_.description as descrip10_0_0_,
            billdetail0_.add_date as add11_0_0_,
            customerde1_.cid as cid10_1_,
            customerde1_.name as name10_1_,
            customerde1_.address as address10_1_,
            customerde1_.city as city10_1_,
            customerde1_.state as state10_1_,
            customerde1_.country as country10_1_,
            customerde1_.mobno as mobno10_1_,
            customerde1_.type as type10_1_,
            customerde1_.dob as dob10_1_,
            customerde1_.anniversery as anniver11_10_1_,
            customerde1_.age_range as age12_10_1_,
            customerde1_.add_date as add13_10_1_,
            customerde1_.status as status10_1_,
            billproduc2_.cid as cid15_2_,
            billproduc2_.qty as qty15_2_,
            billproduc2_.unit_price as unit5_15_2_,
            billproduc2_.selling_price as selling6_15_2_,
            billproduc2_.discount_percent as discount7_15_2_,
            billproduc2_.description as descript8_15_2_,
            billproduc2_.bill_no as bill2_0_0__,
            billproduc2_.product_id as product1_0__,
            billproduc2_.bill_no as bill2_0__,
            product3_.cid as cid4_3_,
            product3_.barcode as barcode4_3_,
            product3_.name as name4_3_,
            product3_.description as descript5_4_3_,
            product3_.quntity as quntity4_3_,
            product3_.unit_price as unit7_4_3_,
            product3_.selling_price as selling8_4_3_,
            product3_.discount_percent as discount9_4_3_,
            product3_.add_date as add10_4_3_,
            product3_.status as status4_3_,
            billpaidde4_.cid as cid8_4_,
            billpaidde4_.bill_no as bill3_8_4_,
            billpaidde4_.amount as amount8_4_,
            billpaidde4_.payment_mode as payment5_8_4_,
            billpaidde4_.dt as dt8_4_,
            billpaidde4_.adddate as adddate8_4_,
            billpaidde4_.bill_no as bill3_0_1__,
            billpaidde4_.id as id1__ 
        from
            xrcwrn_retail_shop.bill_details billdetail0_ 
        left outer join
            xrcwrn_retail_shop.customer_details customerde1_ 
                on billdetail0_.customer_id=customerde1_.id 
        left outer join
            xrcwrn_retail_shop.bill_product billproduc2_ 
                on billdetail0_.bill_no=billproduc2_.bill_no 
        left outer join
            xrcwrn_retail_shop.product product3_ 
                on billproduc2_.product_id=product3_.id 
        left outer join
            xrcwrn_retail_shop.bill_paid_details billpaidde4_ 
                on billdetail0_.bill_no=billpaidde4_.bill_no 
        where
            billdetail0_.bill_no=? 
            and billdetail0_.cid=? 
        group by
            billproduc2_.product_id,
Sep 21, 2014 3:09:28 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    at iland.bill.BillNewAction.insert(BillNewAction.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
            billproduc2_.bill_no
id 82 cid 1
Printing size of obj 
 0
 aa length is 0
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Bill Detail POJO

```
 public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Long billNo;
     private Client client;
     //getter and setter
   }

   public class Client  implements java.io.Serializable {
      private Long id;
     //getter and setter
   }
```

**Edit:** I am inserting record using sql and returning latest inserted Id from here this is ok.
      I find that hibernate is not able to fetch latest record using inserted id.

I am facing same problem in multi places where I am using above same condintion.

My database insert code is: http://pastebin.com/LfP6Hfwc

Comment: Is this your code: iland.bill.BillNewAction.insert(BillNewAction.java:122) ?
What happens in line 122?

Comment: line 122 is showing java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: why are you beginning a new transaction to run a select query at your fetch method?

Comment: @xrcwrn it mean: what is the code in that line? It looks like the Exception originates in your own code. What is the code, and what is the input data when the Exception occurs?

Comment: First of all, what is `bd` in `Map data = dao.insertBill(bd);`? Something seems to go wrong on line `String ss = (String) data.get("status");`, but it's not really clear what goes wrong if I don't know what you're exactly doing with your `Map data`. To me it looks like your database is either empty or you do not connect to your database correctly.

Comment: bd is a BillDetail(pojo class) object

Comment: @ThomasStets on all insertion it is getting auto increment bill no and for each fetch() call it is showing exception

Comment: Ah yeah, this is really strange, I don't understand it either. For some reason `obj = query.list();` creates an empty list. That's why `aa`'s size has a value of 0. And you can't get anything from an empty list, so that's why you get the IndexOutOfBoundsException. But I have no clue how to solve it, sorry. Best of luck to you.

Comment: @xrcwrn Strange. The only difference between the two calls to dao.fetch() seems to be the autoboxing in your manual call.
Have you tried dao.fetch(new Long(56), lc.getClient().getId()); ?

Comment: `dao.fetch(new Long(56), lc.getClient().getId());` its working. What is the problem with `(Long) data.get("billNo")`

Comment: can you put the hql? by setting <property name="show_sql">true</property>

Comment: what was "bd.client.id"??

Comment: @Killer id of business person who is generating bill for their customer.

Comment: bd is for "BillDetails", "client" is for?? and what is the id??

Comment: @Killer included pojo class in question please see

Comment: @Killer got any clue ??

Comment: Could we have the detail of insertBill, and more precisely, the way the Map is returned ?

Comment: @ToYonos Edited question  please see. `public Map insertBill(BillDetails bd) {` is working properly and returning data properly. I am not getting why it is not fetching data. Is there any configuration should made in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: Entity mapping source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`HibernateTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html) is your solution

> This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single Hibernate SessionFactory for transactional data access, but it also supports direct DataSource access within a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource).

Basically, at some point, you'll have to register your dataSource with [`setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html#setDataSource%28javax.sql.DataSource%29)

> Set the JDBC DataSource that this instance should manage transactions for. The DataSource should match the one used by the Hibernate SessionFactory: for example, you could specify the same JNDI DataSource for both.

```
DataSource source = ...; 
hibernateTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
// [...]
Connection con = source.getConnection();
// Do your inserts and stuff
```

Then, use the `hibernateTransactionManager` to fetch your object

```
public List<Object[]> fetch(Long id, long cid)
{
    Session session = hibernateTransactionManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // [...]
```

Comment: I am using struts2 for displaying data in jsp. Is to use `hibernateTransactionManager` spring is required?

Comment: I think it will solve your issue if you want to use both hibernate and plain jdbc. Give it a try.

Comment: Ok any example how to do with struts2

Comment: pleasee see what i tried http://pastebin.com/axPpTwzA it is showing transactionManager is undefined

Comment: @xrcwrn Why do you use JDBC along with Hibernate?

Comment: @xrcwrn hard to say what's wrong but it must be a configuration issue. Try to find example about HibernateTransactionManager implematation

Comment: @RomanC I initially started working with jdbc. so most of the code are written in jdbc.
Now started with hibernate.
For getting data from database I am using Set which is mammed in hbm file it is working.
But for getting multiple data from jsp(for index values) I am unable to use set so I am using list
Now list is not mapped in hbm file so i am saving to db using jdbc.
Second thing is it is defficult for me to insert data in multiple tables using hibernate.

Comment: @RomanC many of my insertion code is written in jdbc and for fetch I am using hibernate and same problem I am facing for other code so Solution for this situation is very important for me

Comment: @RomanC I am trying. getting  undifined `transactionManager` can you see pastbin example what is the problem

Comment: @xrcwrn transactionManager could be injected if you can use it with JDBC Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you might not have flushed your transaction in `insertBill()` method like

```
session.flush();
```

Flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database (i.e. to write changes to the database)

As i suppose you are inserting bill and fetching the same bill in single transaction. So when you are trying to fetch bill, the transaction is not yet committed so that fetch would not be able to fetch expected bill record. `session.flush()` will work in this case for you.

I hope it resolves your query.

Comment: In `insertBill` I am using jdbc code. please see edit section where I have given insertBill Code link

Answer (score 0):

The group by HQL clause doesn't [automatically expand all properties of a given entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping):

> Hibernate also does not currently expand a
>   grouped entity, so you cannot write group by cat if all properties of
>   cat are non-aggregated. You have to list all non-aggregated properties
>   explicitly.

So the query:

```
select distinct bd, sum(bpds.amount) 
from BillDetails as bd
...
group by bpd.id
```

should be changed to:

```
select distinct bd.id, sum(bpds.amount) 
from BillDetails as bd
...
group by bpd.id
```

This way you would fetch the entity id and the amount sum. To fetch the entity you'd have to load it after this query.

Comment: But above query is working properly If already inserted value is called and giving proper result.

Comment: The query is not correct as I told you. You can run a simple "select bd from BillDetails where bd.billNo = :id" without any aggregation so you can see if the record actually exists. If it does then you know the query is broken, so you should change it as I suggested you so.

Comment: Ok. I tried with your mentioned code. but the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

Without using spring we can use [doWork()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work)) and [doReturningWork](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doReturningWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork)).
this can beused with simple Jdbc and hibernate